# Ordenação ASC e DESC sem perder valor de variável

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou tentando realizar uma ordenação de registros em uma página disparando um List/Menu, mas ao disparar o mesmo estou perdendo valores de variáveis de uma primeira seleção.

Ao entrar na página produtos já posiciono uma variável $dep e mostro o resultado.
Ao tentar fazer o filtro por ASC ou DESC a página é recarregada, perdendo assim a pesquisa antes feita e não realiza a ordenação.

Fiz algumas tentativas, guardei as variáveis em sessões e testo o valor da variável filtro:

```
    $dep = $_REQUEST['dep'];
    $subdep = $_REQUEST['sub'];
    
    $_SESSION['dep'] = $dep;
    $_SESSION['sub'] = $subdep;
    
    $filtro = $_POST['filtro'];

    switch ($filtro) {
        case 1:
            $ORDER = " ORDER BY produtos.descricao ASC";
            break;
        case 2:
            $ORDER = " ORDER BY produtos.descricao DESC";
            break;
        default:
            $order = " ORDER BY produtos.descricao ASC";
    }
```

Ao selecionar uma opção do filtro estou disparando o valor da mesma para a página produtos.php e a mesma está assim:

E o meu List/Menu está assim:

```
<select name="filtro" id="filtro" onchange="valueselect(this.value);">
```

```
    
    function valueselect(filtro)
    {
          window.location.href = "produtos.php?filtro="+filtro;
    }
```

O site para exibição é esse:
[Site em Desenvolvimento](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1)

Comment: Se forem vários combos ex: pais, cidade, estado é melhora utilizar ajax para evitar o refresh da tela. Se apenas um você fazer um no `<select>` o comparar os itens do banco com o valor da request nesse caso adicione `selected="selected"` na hora de escrever a `<option>`

Comment: Olá @rray, não estou usando ajax e creio ser esse o problema, mas não consigo achar um exemplo de list/menu com essa característica, valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você carrega a página trocando o `window.location.href`, você faz uma requisição do tipo `GET`, e não `POST`. Porém no PHP você está procurando o valor em `$_POST`. Se você usa sempre `GET` (ou seja, se a informação nunca chega via postagem de um formulário), use `$_GET` no PHP:

```
$filtro = $_GET['filtro'];
```

Se o tipo de requisição variar, você pode usar [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), que junta as informações de POST, GET e dos Cookies (porém cuidado caso haja uma segunda chave `'filtro'` em algum outro lugar):

```
$filtro = $_REQUEST['filtro'];
```

Comment: Olá @bfavaretto, obrigado pela dica, refiz tanto esse código que me passou despercebido, obrigado.